# How to call model method when defining CanCan abilitry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem using a method defined on a model in CanCan abilities:

#### model

```
def Car
    def can_paint?
        ..some conditions, return true or false..
    end
end
```

#### ability

```
can :paint, Car, :user_id => user.id, Car.can_paint?
```

#### CarsController

```
def paint
    @car = ..find the car..
    return redirect_to jobs_path unless can? :paint, @car
    ...
end
```

#### error occurs when the paint action is called

```
/.../app/models/ability.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC 
#error points to the line in ability defined above
```

If I remove `Car.can_paint?` from the ability, then there is no error.

Questions:

1. How to use the `can_paint?` in the abilities?
2. When defining abilities, is there no way to access the actual instance found for the model, i.e. @car
   instead of having to use `Car` so that I could write:
   `can :paint, Car, :user_id => user.id ***if @car.can_paint?***`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `can` method takes a hash of conditions to check on. In your example, when you call this:

```
can :paint, Car, :user_id => user.id, Car.can_paint?
```

It is essentially passing this:

```
can :paint, Car, {:user_id => user.id, true}
```

Which is not a valid hash, and likely the source of the `expecting tASSOC` error. (You are also calling an instance method on a class - but that's not the real issue here)

However, you can pass a block as a condition, so something like the following would work to check the actual object:

```
can :paint, Car, :user_id => user.id do |car|
  car.can_paint?
end
```

This will correctly check if a user has permission to paint an instance of a car.

For reference, keep an eye on CanCan's docs, as they provide some pretty good examples -  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Comment: Hey, that works! I did look at the docs, but it wasn't obvious how to use a class instance as opposed to the class name to do this (even in the block we pass in the class name).

Comment: Glad it works! To go a little deeper, you're not actually passing the class name to the block (Car vs car - it is case sensitive) but naming the variable to use for the code in the block (in this case, the object passed to the block is an instance of Car, as specified in the docs). To see this, try changing "do |car|" to "do |car_instance| car_instance.can_paint?", and your code should run exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering about `can :paint, Car ....`; clearly the class name `Car` is being passed there, so how on earth am I able to access the Car's instance variable on which I am calling the `can_paint?` method?! Lots more reading to do on CanCan..

Comment: Again, reading the docs, the 'Block Conditions' section is all about using a block to check an instance of the class. Think about it from the top down - you have to specify the class before you can specify what instance of a class to check on (and CanCan short-circuits on just the Class if no instance is present to check against). I was just trying to clear up the confusion about passing the class name as the block argument - it's definitely a common stumbling block.